# Error when installing software using a GUI

Tags: debian, linux-mint, polkit

I'm running Feren OS which is based off of Ubuntu, Linux Mint, and Debian. Whenever I try to install or update software using a GUI like Store or Update Manager, I get this error:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

The update application is called mintUpdate and the store is just Feren Store.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the policy kit.

I am able to use apt just fine, this only happens with GUI-based updates and installations.

Comment: Welcome to the the Unix and Linux stack exchange! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to the site. Take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) if you are not familiar with how this site works. What application are you using to update? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518296/error-when-installing-software-using-a-gui#) your post to include these details. Thank you!

Comment: I already said I'm using Update Manager. I think it also goes by something like mintUpdate maybe.

Comment: Using the exact name of the application helps because that is a generic dbus error message. Is there any additional output or any information in the Information window of mintUpdater or relevant log? can you update manually via `apt`? Again, please edit your post to include this information instead of commenting. Thank you.